# Integrating news ticker and drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, news-ticker

I am trying to integrate scroll(news ticker) and Drag scrollable.I have almost done it.when i change the parent div width to 100% my drag part is not working, when i reduced to 600 px it is working fine.

Could anyone please suggest me whats going wrong with this.

Scroll part : http://jquery-plugins.net/jquery-auto-scroller

Drag part : http://hitconsultants.com/dragscroll_scrollsync/scrollpane.html

customized Solution : http://jsfiddle.net/3L6Gm/

here is the function am calling

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        // Set drag scroll on first descendant of class dragger on both selected elements
        $('#inner').dragscrollable({ dragSelector: '.dragger:first', acceptPropagatedEvent: false, contentDiv: 'vmarquee', scrollSpeed: 5, parentDiv: 'inner' });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have achieved it. With some help of js.

Here is the working solution

http://jsfiddle.net/8Pbqb/

```
    $(window).load(function () { autoScroller('vmarquee', 4, 'inner') });
```